Prepopulate form entries in a SharePoint Custom Form
I have a SharePoint custom form with an extra button, besides the submit button. Once the form is filled out and this button is clicked, the form should be submitted. The form then should be reload as new form with some entries (e.g. title) prepopulated  from the last submitted on.
What I´ve done so far is this:
OnSuccess:
If(
    varCopyMasterData = true,
    Set(varTitle, DataCardValue3.Text); // Set the title variable after form submission
    ResetForm(Self); // Reset the form to prepare for a new submission
    NewForm(SharePointForm1) // Reload the form as a new form
);
RequestHide(); // Close the form when the action completes

OnSelect:
Set(varCopyMasterData, true); // Flag to copy the data
SubmitForm(SharePointForm1); // Submit the form and wait for OnSuccess logic to run

DataCardValue3.Default: varTitle

But this doesn´t to work. It seems, that the title field is always prepopulated with the first entry in the list and not the saved varTitle value.
If I put a label outside the SharePointForm1, it will show me the correct value but the varTitle in the datacard value shows the first entry in the list.
Any help is appreciated.
